# Who was the man whom Athena gave the gift of prophecy, and from whom did Athena learn it from?

Tags: greek, athena

I remember a myth I read once. It talked of a man who was the only mortal to be taught prophecy, or some form of it, by Athena, Greek goddess of wisdom. But I cannot recall the name of this man. Nor was I told how Athena came to know or learn prophecy.

Who taught Athena the art of prophecy? Was it taught to Athena by Pallas, Pallas's father Triton, Pallas's mother or some other manner of being?

Who was this man that was taught by Athena?

I ask this next question because prophecy is not usually associated with Athena.

Comment: Athena was born an adult, fully formed from the head of Zeus. She had no mother and and her father was not Triton. Triton would be her nephew.

Comment: The mother of Triton was what I meant. Athena's, Greek goddess of Wisdom, mother was Metis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The man that Athena gave the gift of prophecy, or more exactly augury, was [Tiresias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiresias). He had seen her bathing naked in a stream, and in retaliation she made him blind. His mother, Chariclo, one of Athena's nymphs, begged Athena to undo her curse, but she could not. Athena then cleaned his ears, enabling him to understand birdsong, from which he could foretell the future.

She did not teach him it, and as far as I am aware she did not herself have it.